# Accessing windows network share as logged in user from a web app?

Tags: php, iis, windows-share

After a user logs in to my web app (authenticating against Active Directory/LDAP) I need to connect to a windows network share on the same network (with their credentials/impersonating them) and access files they have access to so that they can be made available in the web app. This is running on IIS/Windows.

The only way I found that partially works, is mapping a network drive using their credentials, querying for the files they requested, then deleting the network drive (which isn't deleted most of the time), **this seems insecure and inefficient for production use**.

Is there a better option?

Comment: If it is not secure, then you can try to use other authentication methods. Regarding the inefficiency, you need to analyze what is causing it.